# Limit RAM Usage to a CPP application

Tags: ram

I have 3 GB RAM. Is there a way to allocate only 512MB of RAM to a C++ application?

Else

Is there a way to reduce my RAM to 512MB for a while for testing purpose?

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: If you're running under a VM (ex. VMWare) you can easily control RAM and other settings

Comment: Hi Thanks for Quick response. I am using Windows7. Is there is other way to get it done instead of VM?

Answer (score 4):

Use [SetProcessWorkingSetSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Sets the minimum and maximum working set sizes for the specified process.

Comment: Thank you so much Reno. Can i set from the commandline while the process running? If so , can you give me a simple example, i am new to this...

Comment: No, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234%28VS.85%29.aspx). You need the handle to the process. If you are new to this I suggest that you should learn a bit about windows programming first.